# Using hidden file input elements using the click() method

Tags: javascript, html

Is the `if` statement needed in this [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Using_hidden_file_input_elements_using_the_click%28%29_method)? Doesn't it work like this:

```
var fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
  fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem");

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    fileElem.click();
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
}, false);
```

Comment: This might cause NPE exception if fileElem is null.

Comment: @Nisha javascript doesn't have NPE, it would just be an undefined element error

Comment: @RUJordan: Yeah you are right. Thats what i meant. Confused with Java and Javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its needed.What if your fileElem give you exceptions.You have to handle it properly using if statement.

Comment: "_What if your fileElem give you exceptions._" How can it happen? Would you mind providing an example?

Comment: what if you get undefined value set to fileElem? it will give you exception right.You have handle it.As a programmer you should follow some standards.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% needed, so long as you're absolutely sure that `fileElem` is always defined. If it's not defined, you risk getting a console error along the lines of:

```
TypeError: cannot call method 'click' of undefined
```

So in short: no it's not needed, but not using it would be risking an error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as you see in the reference it's defined, right? Then it's redundant.

Comment: @Mori what happens if `fileElem` is overwritten, or the scope is altered, or the element is removed from the DOM? Like I said, it's not needed, but it's simply better practice to keep it in check.

Answer (score 0):

Its not completely necessary if statement. If you have defined file element then undefined exception won't occurs.

and without if its working: see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qqL7c/)

Code:

```
var fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
  fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem");

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    fileElem.click();
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
}, false);
```

Comment: Yes @RUJordan. But unfortunately Jsfiddle link answer need code also.